# split() function does not work embedded in another function

Tags: r, function, split

I want to code a function which has a state abbreviation called `state` as its only input variable.

The function should then ..

- read a certain csv file with `read.csv()`
- split the data frame up by the state abbreviations with `split()`
- return only the data with the state abbreviation `state`

I know it is kind of a filter function, but I explicitly want to do it with the `split` function.

Here is my code:

```
best <- function(state) {

## Read the data 
data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

## Split data up by the 'State' column
data_split <- split(data, data$State)

## Return data with state in 'State' column
data_split$state

}

## Executing the function
best("NY") ## returns NULL
```

When I execute these lines without using a function, it is working. So I suppose that there is a problem with putting the input variable `state` as an argument in `data_split$state`.

Thanks for your help.

Best wishes,
Marcus

Comment: try return `data_split[[state]]`?

Comment: @mt1022 My thoughts exactly :-)

Comment: Thank you guys, it works well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using:

```
data_split[[state]]
```

Full code:

```
best <- function(state) {
    data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
    # split data on the _column_ called 'State'
    data_split <- split(data, data$State)
    # return the entry in the list whose _name_ is contained in 'state'
    data_split[[state]]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works :) Have you an explanation for that behavior? So why can I call `state$NY` but not `a <- NY; state$a`?

Comment: @ashbounty Because when you say `state$a` you are telling R to access the _column_ named `a` in your list/data frame.  Using the double bracket subset lets you specify a string name, and this works.